# In a list of dictionaries changing a specific element will change all the others as well

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I found this strange property when considering a list of dictionaries. Consider the following:

```
my_list=[{}]*3
my_list[0]['a']=1
print my_list
```

why are all elements of the list changed at the same time, even though I specifically tried to change the `0` element of the list alone?

What should I do if I want to handle each dictionary separately?

More generally, is there a better way to store a certain number of dictionaries, other than making a list of them?

Comment: don't call your variable `list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this might seem a little strange at first but you need to understand how dictionaries are treated in python.

In the first line :  You are creating 3 copies of `{}` and storing it into a list.

Now what happens here :

1. An empty dictionary is created `{}`
2. Same dictionary is referenced and stored 3 time in the list.
3. You change value in the dictionary, it reflects on all the instances of the dictionary stored in list.

How to work this out:

```
my_list = []
for i in range(3):
    my_list.append({})

my_list[0]['a']=1

print(my_list)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{'a': 1}, {}, {}]
```

Comment: TY! 
why does it only work like this for dictionaries? For example, if I do `a=5` and `my_list=[a]*3`, then `my_list[0]=2` will only change the first element.

Comment: @3sm1r Completely different operations. In the case in the question you are mutating the object to which `my_list[0]` points (i.e. the dictionary). In your new example you are reassigning `my_list[0]` to point to a different object (and in any case the existing object to which it points, the integer `5`, is immutable).

Answer (score 1):

When you create `my_list=[{}]*3` the same reference has taken in `n` number of times.

So, avoid doing that when you want to change specific values.

You can try like this:

`my_list=[{} for i in range(3)]`

Comment: It will also be instructive to evaluate `[id(d) for d in my_list]` and compare the two cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
list=[{}]*3
```

When you are doing this you are creating the same object 3 times with the same reference. So if you change one all will be changed. In python, it is not required to declare the size of your dictionary. Just declare an empty dictionary.